# How to get id of all the events in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

For getting the id of the event clicked i used the below code it worked but i want to get id of all the events in the calendar and store them in an array and display in php script.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){

                    var order_id = jQuery.trim(calEvent.id)

                    $('input[name="order_id"]').val(order_id);

                    var offset = $('.city-search').offset();
                    var top = parseInt(offset.top) - Math.abs(parseInt($('.city-search').css("top")));
                    $(window).scrollTop(top);



            },
```

Comment: its javascript question not php  and codeigniter

Comment: i am making a codeigniter app thats why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try [clientEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents) and the ID key is `_id`

```
var all_event = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
all_event.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.start._i - b.start._i;
});
var all_id = all_event.map(x => x._id);

console.log(all_id)
// ["_fc4", "_fc5", "_fc1", "_fc3"...]
```

Comment: Thankyou @ewwink it worked but the ids are not sorted acc to dates how to get sorted id like the after event id of 1st nov the id of 2nd nov should come.do you have any idea how to do that?